# How to provide confirmation in windows iot core for custom pairing

Tags: c#, bluetooth, windows-10-iot-core, raspberry-pi3

I am trying to do a custom device pairing using Raspberry Pi 3 running on windows IoT Core. The official sample provided on github for device Enumeration and Custom Pairing(Scenario 9) https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/DeviceEnumerationAndPairing/cs
works fine on a local machine where we can have user interaction.

But how to do it on windows iot core. Even the sample code says

> // Windows itself will pop the confirmation dialog as part of "consent" if this is running on Desktop or Mobile
>
> // If this is an App for 'Windows IoT Core' where there is no Windows Consent UX, you may want to provide your own confirmation.

```
private async void PairingRequestedHandler(
        DeviceInformationCustomPairing sender,
        DevicePairingRequestedEventArgs args)
    {
        switch (args.PairingKind)
        {
            case DevicePairingKinds.ConfirmOnly:
            // Windows itself will pop the confirmation dialog as part of "consent" 
            //if this is running on Desktop or Mobile
            // If this is an App for 'Windows IoT Core' where there is no Windows 
            //Consent UX, you may want to provide your own confirmation.

                args.Accept();
                break;
```

How do I provide my own confirmation? Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The confirmation is optional and is only done on Desktop and Mobile as part of the system-level user experience.  By calling the [Accept](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt608811.aspx) method the pairing will proceed.

If you wish to provide a confirmation things get tricky because [MessageDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.popups.messagedialog.aspx) isn't currently supported on IoT Core: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/win10/unavailableapis

As an alternative, others have proposed [creating your own UserControl](http://bitaware.altervista.org/messagedialog-for-iot/) or [using a Flyout](http://www.embedded101.com/Blogs/David-Jones/entryid/742/Windows-10-IoT-Core-Take-Two) to mimic the experience.

Answer (score 0):

The official IoTCoreDefaultApp is using the Visibility property of "Yes" and "No" button to mimic the behavior.

[image]

Check out the sample code in https://github.com/ms-iot/samples/tree/develop/IoTCoreDefaultApp.

Especially, watch out for

```
private async void DisplayMessagePanel(string confirmationMessage, MessageType messageType)
```

from line 536~562 in https://github.com/ms-iot/samples/blob/develop/IoTCoreDefaultApp/IoTCoreDefaultApp/Views/Settings.xaml.cs.

This is the trick you can use in your IoT app.